# Граница блока вдавленной линией

Tags: css3, html, css

Добрый день.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать границу блока вдавленной линией, шириной 1px (примерно), в сети вроде и много примеров, но как-то всё но это.

Я думаю, нужно как-то использовать box-shadow  и как-то минусом ставить тень, но разобраться не могу пока.

Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Что-то я не соображу, что вы подразумеваете под вдавленной линией. Можно пример?

Comment: Можно использовать border - groove, inset.

Comment: Да, примерно так, я ещё цвет немного подберу и нормально. Спасибо!

Comment: @soledar10, запости ответ как ответ, а не как комментарий.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;    
}
body{
  background: #555;
}
.block{
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  min-height: 150px;
  border: 1px inset #ddd;    
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```